# Ag-grids - Forced Reflow is likely a performance bottleneck

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm integrating ag-grid in my JSF application. When i run ag-grid in simple application it works great. But when the same grid in used in a page contains more number of components, clicking on a cell takes nearly 0.5 to 1 seconds to move focus to that cell but keyboard navigation is working faster. On analysing with chrome performance monitor we found that mouse down event is consuming time. Chrome is showing below warning message.

> Forced Reflow is likely a performance bottleneck

How to overcome this performance issue?

Ag grid version: 17

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This issue was fixed in aggridenterprise-17.1.1